# Lost About where to start to become a web designer

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, photoshop

i have long wanted to be a web designer, self taught.  My aim for this year is to design a wordpress theme from scratch.  i dunno where to start from.

learn photoshop, html, js, php, mysql in which order? where to get the learning resources etc.

what do i need to learn?

any advice will be hugely appreciated...

Comment: Voting to close as off topic, this is not a programming question. There is a Stack Exchange page for webmasters though.

Comment: In general: learn photoshop, (x)html, css, js and read about the box models. For templating only a little PHP is necessary and no mysql.

Comment: You can also **not** have to learn photoshop and instead have a friend that wants to get started but has more art skill (or vice versa). This way you can concentrate on just programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In building websites there are different disciplines. In a nutshell:

- Designer. Draws the website, how it should look. Defines the style of the website. Uses mainly PhotoShop.
- Interaction Designer. Defines where each feature goes and how it should work.
- Client side developer. Writes client side code. HTML/CSS templates, maybe a bit of JavaScript, although there is a big difference between HTML and JavaScript and the skills you need. Maybe you should even consider HTML/CSS and JavaScript to different disciplines.
- Server side developer. Writes server side code (PHP/ASP/...). Will probably need some SQL knowledge as well.
- Database administrator. Keeps the database running. Actually not part of the web-building disciplines list.

So, you need to think whether you want to be *all* these persons, or just one or a few of them. I personally so mainly PHP development and a little JavaScript. In work, I hardly do any HTML/CSS, because this is done by another guy. If you got a fellow that wants to build websites too, you maybe could check where each others skills lie. If you're a programmer, you can focus on serverside and JavaScript, where he can build the lot in PhotoShop, think about the interactions, and build HTML/CSS. You will only need a little of eachothers skills for sparring, and you could build great things together because each of you has their speciality.

If you need to do it on your own, and you haven't got any of these skills yet, I would just start somewhere and at least try everything. Keep your learning projects simple, and don't start mixing 5 of the names disciplines. If you want to start using HTML techniques, don't mind tha fancy looks yet. Draw a few lines in paint and just pretend you got all these gradients and spiffy looks. With a bit of make belief, if you try one of these skills you don't need any of the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aiming for designer or developer or both? A designer doesn't neccesairily need to be able to make a fancy AJAX page that does all sorts of mysql things. Mysql isn't needed at all for a designer.

Now if you wan't not only to design the template, but give a complete sollution to you customers your need to do a lot more.

The order I would do it would be:

- photoshop / drawing / 'designing' ->
  make the actual thing you want to
  sell (the image, the 'vision' etc)
- Some usability etc: Show your clients why your design is better,
  why it's a good page and why your site 'works'
- HTML: you can make a mock-up for your site so they can actually click
  trough it. You can also sell this as a base for their programmers.
- javascript, AJAX etc: You can make your mock-up better like this!

Now you want to sell complete templates (not just the design), you'll have to start learning the ins-and-outs of wordpress templates. that's kinda like a language an sich.

Get some basic PHP skills if you want, cause it can get you out of trouble, but it's not a big amount.

Mysql is only needed if you want to start adding functionality etc, but now you're really talking about a second job :)

Comment: i'm aiming for both developer and designer :)  Thanks for the reply...gives a clearer plan of action in my head.